# Submenu is not deployed when mounted on the server

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, iis

I have a problem and the assembly, the application, the server, and the routine tests of the changes that I was made to perceive the submenu that in the theory of duties deploy, it does not, but if I execute the project if I the sample know what is due? It is already in several browsers, delete everything that is stored in memory and still still without verse. The application is made in asp mvc, it has the template by default.

App mounted on the server:

[image]

App running in local from VB2017:

[image]

**HTML**:

```html
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a class=" dropdown-toggle">Opeacion</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cambio de Precio Articulos", "CambioPrecioArticulos", "Adquisiciones")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Carga masiva de Articulos", "Index", "Adquisiciones")</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**CCS**:

```css
/*
    Parte agregada
*/
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just had to refer to the css

Comment: It often happen that when you update a CSS file, the cache of the browser need to be cleared for the new changes to take action, have you tried this, i.e, clearing the **browser's CHACHE**?

Comment: Yes, clean the browser's cache memory, but still I can not see it reflected when I start the page, it only works when I'm running it with VB2017 @D.Smania

Comment: @andresmartinez inspect your sub-menu html using browser Developer tools to ensure it is rendering properly. Also, check that your css file(s) are loading and there is no 404 error in Developer tools Network tab

Comment: thanks @MohsinMehmood !! , I just had to refer to the css